# Self looks like an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, self

I'm building an app whereas I have a UITableViewController set up as static and grouped. I'm using StoryBoard.

I have a breakpoint in my code where self looks like an array as it says "0 Objects" while it's a UITableViewController. Does anyone have a clue on why this is? Same happens if I use the class name as a cast. Just need an explanation for this.

[image]

[image]

V[0] is supposed to be an NSMutableArray, I init it like this, oldArray contains 3 objects (valid and correct objects)

```
_newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
```

But it doesn't look correct, neither does it work properly or log any objects. It logs out as nil when doing po _newArray

Thanks!

**Update: fix**

I changed it to a property instead of declaring it in @interface like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *newArray;
```

and populated it using a function like so:

```
self.newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self myArray]];
```

whereas myArray is a function with NSArray as return type. Looks like that fixed it, any comments on that?

Comment: I have seen the same too. Seems like bug in the Xcode

Comment: @Azat really frustrating, I can't view the class properties

Comment: Xcode always has issues with breakpoints, UI debugger etc, so if you want to see something of your object, `NSLog` it :)

Comment: @Azat Yeah :P check out my edit, the "V[0]" is supposed to be array, why is it like that? It doesn't appear to be initialised correctly or something

Comment: Type `po self` at the `(lldb)` prompt to see what `self` actually is.

Comment: That tool really not reliable, you can either use `NSLog` or `po self`

Comment: @AaronBrager it logs out the correct UITableViewController followed by 0x1605121e0

Comment: For you people who downvote, please be kind enough to leave a comment telling me the reason. I haven't got any possibility of improving if you don't give constructive feedback. Closing a question without telling me why is useless

Comment: The Xcode debugger variable display is buggy.  Never trust it.  Either use NSLog or use `po` in the console window.